# How to prevent Parsley validation when submit form

Tags: parsley.js

Currently if using Parsley, it will auto validate when we click submit button

What I want to do is

1. When user submit button, handle with jQuery
2. Depends on field value, for example STATUS is DRAFT, do not trigger the Parsley validation
3. If STATUS is PUBLISH, trigger the Parsley validation

Question is, how do I prevent Parsley from auto validate when I click submit button so I can achieve the scenario above?

```
$(".review_form").submit(function (event) {
    // get status value

    var status = $("#status").val();

    // continue the form submission without validating
    if (status === 'DRAFT') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
       // let Parsley validate the form
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want validation feedback in draft mode, you should listen to your `#status` changing and call `destroy()` on the Parsley form or re-init it accordingly.

If you'd potentially like validation feedback but still allow the form to submit, that is way more difficult than it should be, sorry. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1324).

Comment: Hi is this correct? Because when I test Parsley still validating the form when submit

https://pastebin.com/ZTrr8kPX

Comment: Hi sorry to trouble you again but when I use your code I have syntax error

Uncaught Type Error: t.getAttribute is not a function
    at y._submit

https://pastebin.com/yi4mZue6

Comment: Mmm, not quite what I meant, but then what I meant doesn't quite work. I opened https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1324 please subscribe to it.

Comment: Noted. Meanwhile I can settle with destroy() and reinit()

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune It would be really great to give validation feedback but still allow form submission, got stuck on this earlier. You've said it's more difficult than it should be, if you have an example of how to do it anyway, despite being difficult, sharing would be cool ^^.